# Will Xcode 9 beta make my ObjC projects unusable with Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, xcode9-beta

I'd like to use the Xcode 9 beta new features but I'm worried about backwards compatibility after working with the beta version. I've had such problems with past Xcode beta versions (since it made storyboards unusable with previous versions). I've tried loading test projects (ObjC and Swift) without any problem but I'd like to know if someone here can confirm this point since I need to upload to App Store frequently and I'll need Xcode 8 to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's beta software. I don't think anyone can really give you that guarantee. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Why don't you keep both Xcodes?

Comment: Yes, I know there's no guarantee and I pretend to use both Xcodes. My concern is about changes in project files that prevent from loading in Xcode 8 to submit to App Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure about the ObjC projects in particular, but after opening my storyboard in `Xcode9-Beta` and then in `Xcode8`, all my `UILabel`s disappeared. They are there, you can select/edit them, but they are just not visible.

But besides, if you are using version control, you can always rollback :)

Comment: Mmmm… that's something. Enough for me. Thank you enigma.

Comment: glad that I could help :)